# java after reading text from file, prints will "null" in the beginning

Tags: java, string, null

I've readed from the .txt file this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

but after reading it and then outputing I get this:

```
null<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

null at the beginning, this is the method:

```
public class Filer {

    private static String str;
    public static String read(String file) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                str += sCurrentLine;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return str;

    }
}
```

the returned string its being outputed by `System.out.println`

I've tried to check that string by `str.indexOf("null");` or `str.indexOf("\0");` but I get -1

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the very first iteration of your loop. The value of `str` is null, and the value of `sCurrentLine` is `"<?xml version="1.0"?>"`.

In string concatenation, a null reference is converted into a string of "null". For example:

```
String x = null;
String y = "a";
String z = x + y; // "nulla"
```

So on your first iteration, when you execute:

```
str += sCurrentLine;
```

the value of `str` will be `"null<?xml version="1.0"?>"`

You *could* just initialize `str` to `""`... but I wouldn't.

There's no reason why it should be a static variable anyway - would you really want to keep the old value hanging around even if the method is called again? That would be very odd. It should be a *local* variable.

Also, you shouldn't use string concatenation in a loop like this - it's horrible in terms of performance, because it needs to keep copying the old data. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

I wouldn't catch exceptions like that either - do you really want the caller not to know that anything went wrong? Just declare that your method can throw `IOException`.

Additionally, I wouldn't use `FileReader` myself - it gives you no control over the encoding used to read the file - it will always use the platform default encoding, which may be inappropriate. I'd use a `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `InputStreamReader`. You can then use a `try-with-resources` statement in Java 7 to close the `FileInputStream` automatically.

So, with all those changes, your code would become something like this:

```
public static String read(String file) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note that this will convert a multi-line file into a *single* line of text - use `builder.append("\n")` or something similar in the loop if you want to preserve the number of lines (but don't care about line separators). If you want to preserve the exact line endings, don't use `readLine` - just read characters into a buffer instead.

Also, consider using a third party library such as [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to do all this instead - for example, you could use [`Files.toString()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: chosed this answer as accepted for the full builder example, thank you again

Answer (score 5):

When you concatenate a `null` reference with a string, it is converted to `"null"` string, and then concatenation is performed.

This is specified in [JLS - Section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

Now, when you declare an instance or static reference field, without initializing to any value, it will be initialized to default value - `null`, as in your declaration:

```
private static String str;  // This is `null`.
```

Then for the first iteration of the loop:

```
str += sCurrentLine;
```

is equivalent to:

```
str = null + sCurrentLine;  // Hence the result.
```

As for your `str.indexOf()` query, I don't know where you are testing the index, because it should return the index of `null` that is `0`, provided, you used that method after the loop, as shown in the below snippet:

```
String str = null;
String str2 = str + "someString";
System.out.println("Index of null in : " + str2 + " : " + str2.indexOf("null"));
```

This will output to you:

```
Index of null in : nullsomeString : 0
```

---

Also, while performing string concatenation inside such a loop, which you can't control, when it ends, and even in general, you should use `StringBuilder` instance, to avoid creating intermediate string instances:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append(sCurrentLine);
```

Comment: also why the indexOf didn't find the null that was concatinated?, it returned me -1

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String str;
```

is null. You have to initialize it.

```
private static String str = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

do this `private static String str = "";`.
By default, your `str` variable is `null` so while concatenating `null` is used.

Initialize it to a blank string as I've shown.